# Forced reflow violation and page offset - is it normal?

Tags: javascript, offset, reflow

When adding a position: fixed on-scroll on my navbar the DOM throws the error: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took ms, on every scroll event. From my understanding (and Googling) this means there is layout thrashing everytime a scroll event happens due to new calculation.

My question is; is this a problem? I can't really crack the code of how to improve it to remove the violation, hence why I wanted to hear if this is 'standard' behaviour when working with scroll offsets.

The code I'm using is below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
  window.addEventListener('scroll', addPositionFixed);

  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  function addPositionFixed() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you considered https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning The reflow is indeed caused by the access to `pageYOffset`, there isn't much you can do about it, maybe an IntersectionObserver could avoid a bit of recalcs, but sticky position would be by far the best option.

Comment: I tried that when I started out, but I could not get it to work, for some reason. It would had been a nice solution tho!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that seemed to work and throw no errors:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Atleast that does not throw any errors anymore!